# UI won't load until click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I've recently launched my Xamarin app on iOS for the first time. The app works perfectly on Android. However, on iOS the UI won't load fully until I touch the screen. This is related to binding and ui elements which are being created dynamically. For example, this button:

```
<local:MainMenuButton Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="{Type local:page2}" CornerRadiusExtended="{Binding LeftCornersRounded}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference ModelButton}}"/>
```

won't change it's height to ModelButton's height. Also, `ImageButton`s are completely invisible (the image is not being loaded). Everything starts working after I click the screen. Does someone know what's going on?

[EDIT]: This applies even to controls I don't reference in code to. For example:

```
<ImageButton Style="{StaticResource UiButton}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding SetLanguageCommand}" CommandParameter="EN" Source="{helpers:ImageResourceExtension imagesource.png}"/>

// Extension code

[ContentProperty("Source")]
public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Source == null)
            return null;

        var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source);

        return imageSource;
    }
}
```

The ImageButton won't load it's source until click. If I remove binding and directly enter the source, everything works fine.
I used debugger to check whether the extension code executes at page launch or after click, and it turned out that it runs at launch. For some reason though, the image is still being displayed after click.

Comment: Hi , have a try with updating model data in `OnAppearing()` method.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Okey, could you show some code about updating model data when launch app in ContentPage .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I edited my post. The problem applies even to controls which I don't reference to in code, so it's probably not about updating model data.

Comment: Got it, have a try with setting binding mode to TwoWay . `HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference ModelButton},Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Didn't work for me. I tried creating a new project and copying all the files there, but it didn't' help too, so I submitted a support ticket using MS Support page.

Comment: Could you share your solution on Github. Or a new solution where you can replicate what you are seeing. Your error seems very odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received a reply from Microsoft Support. They found the root of the issue. It was a NuGet package called Forms9Patch which caused the problem (https://baskren.github.io/Forms9Patch/). It's unclear how it could affect the rendering, but removing the package from the project resolved the issue. I'll contact the package owner with this.